# Is it possible to safely dispose object that owns thread while running in that thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have an object A, that contains an instance of object B. Object B creates a thread which dequeues tasks. Eventually, this thread receives an event that requires disposing object A after the event is processed (it essentially represents a terminal event). It seems like there isn't any safe way to dispose A which I am running on the background thread because A owns the thread essentially. Would I have to dispose A on another thread or is there a safe way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as A doesn't explicitly try to kill the thread, it is OK.
"B" holding the thread object isn't what keeps the thread object running -- the thread itself will do that.
The Thread object won't be released until the thread itself exits, and all other explicit references to the Thread are released.